# Find and replace * in strings using regular expressions in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a large X12 EDI file with many description strings (1000s).  These description strings can be found before, after and between other strings that have the same delimiter of `*`.

All description strings start with the tag `REF*TC**` and end with the character `~`.

I need to find and replace all `*` that occur between these two tags, without touching the other strings, in this example the DTM string.

I am including an example of two description strings as they would be found in the file.  As you can see, the first description string contains the `*` that I'm needing to replace, the second description string doesn't contain any `*` that are needing to be replaced.

```
~REF*TC**BLAH*BLAH*~REF*TC**BLAHBLAH~REF*TC***BLAH~DTM*010*20110329~
```

desired output:

```
~REF*TC**BLAHBLAH~REF*TC**BLAHBLAH~REF*TC**BLAH~DTM*010*20110329~
```

I am using C#

This is what I have so far.

find expression:  `REF\*TC\*\*(.{0,}?)(\*+)(.{0,}?)(\**)(.{0,}?)(\**)~`

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I've come up with:

```
var str = "~REF*TC**BLAH*BLAH*~REF*TC**BLAHBLAH~REF*TC***BLAH~DTM*010*20110329~";
var result = (new Regex(@"(?<pre>REF\*TC\*\*)(?<text>.*?)(?<post>~)")).Replace(str,(m) =>
{
    return String.Join(String.Empty,new String[]{
        m.Groups["pre"].Value,
        m.Groups["text"].Value.Replace("*",String.Empty),
        m.Groups["post"].Value
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://www.ideone.com/rzNAw)**

That's just based on what you've provided, not 100% sure what you're going for though, to be honest.

Comment: it's not pure regex, combo of regex and .Net .Replace, but it works.  Any idea on how to do it with pure Regex?

Comment: @Jason: You *may* be able to get tricky using a negative look-ahead and quantifiers to disqualify the additional `*`, but I doubt it. I'm thinking you're going to have to do it this way. That's what the `.Replace` methods exists for afterall.

Comment: Yeah, I was going down the same track with the negatie look ahead, oh well.  Thanks for the quick response.  I have a prebuilt app that just takes the giant string and does iterative regex find and replaces.  Was hoping to not have to recode the app, but will do it, and just include your logic.  Thanks.

Comment: Brad, anyway to do this without lambda expressions?  I'm in .NET 2.0.

Comment: @Brad, can you give me the code I'd need in .NET 2.0 without the lambda expression?

Comment: @Jason, break the lambda out in to a separate function, then reference the function name as the second parameter in the replace method. e.g. `public string MyReplacer(Match m){ /*lambda code */} ... .Replace(str,new MatchEvaluator(MyReplacer)); ...`

Answer (score 1):

Regex is awesome, but as the famous quote goes, `Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.`  Skip the regex and just use string methods on it.  You could go as simple as splitting it on the `REF*TC**` start tags and then replacing all the `*` characters, or you could try for something more sophisticated.  Don't go all the way for regex when simple string methods will do.

EDIT:

Here's a real simple example:

```
string[] lines = file.Split("REF*TC**");
for(int i=0;i<lines.Length;i++)
{
    lines[i] = lines[i].Replace("*", "");
}
string output = string.Join("REF*TC**", lines);
```

You may have to clean up an extra "REF*TC**" at the end, I don't remember exactly how Join() handles it.  Anyways, that should do it.

Comment: Problem is, if you see in my example, there are other lines that can happen after the REF*TC** that can't be modified.  For example: ~DTM*010*20110329~ needs to be left alone.  Thank you for your quick reply though.

Comment: The description strings are really found intermixed with other strings within the file, so just splitting the strings by REF*TC** would take in too much data into the string array it creates.

Comment: I see - I didn't understand that from the example - maybe I didn't read the question closely enough.